# How to install Ionic media plugin?

Tags: ionic4

just install fresh Ionic4 framework, create tabs  starter project and try install media plugin as described here
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/#installation

But nothing worked and I received the following error:

> [ng] ERROR in src/app/tab2/tab2.page.ts(14,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Media'.**

my ionic info

```
$ ionic info

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.9.0 (C:\Users\RAMS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.3
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.3

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : none
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (1 plugins total)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk)
   NodeJS            : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 7
```

here is my tab2.page.ts

```
import {Media, MediaObject} from '@ionic-native/media';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-tab2',
    templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})

export class Tab2Page {

    constructor(private media: Media) {
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there was an issue with your installation?

Maybe you could try reinstalling:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
npm install @ionic-native/media
```

Comment: can you verify that it's properly installed: $ npm ls @ionic-native/media ?